# Dynamic alertBody for CloudKit notifications

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, icloud, cloudkit

I'm trying to use CloudKit to send push notifications to users that have subscribed to a channel that releases episodes. I'm able to create the `CKRecord`, subscribe users, and receive notifications when new episodes are released though I would like my `alertBody` to be the **newly posted** episode's caption.

Right now the push notification shows the `alertBody` of the original `CKRecord` used to save the subscription.

I have read about people explaining to use a Localization.Strings file but don't know how that would help me here. Is this even possible with CloudKit?

```
static func registerSubscriptionWith(ID: String) {
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "channelID == %@", ID)
    let subscription = CKQuerySubscription(recordType: "Episode", predicate: predicate, options: .firesOnRecordCreation)
    
    let myContainer = CKContainer.default()
    let publicDatabase = myContainer.publicCloudDatabase
    
    let recordID = CKRecord.ID(recordName: ID)
    publicDatabase.fetch(withRecordID: recordID) { (record, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            if record != nil {
                let notification = CKSubscription.NotificationInfo()
                notification.title = record!["channelName"]
                notification.alertBody = record!["caption"]
                notification.soundName = "default"
                
                subscription.notificationInfo = notification
                
                publicDatabase.save(subscription) { result, error in
                    if error != nil {
                        print(error!.localizedDescription)
                    } else {
                        print("Success subscribing user to episode notifications")
                    }
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so why don't you use notification.alertBody = NSLocalizedDescription(record!["caption"]) ?

Comment: Hey @Chris, can you show me how to implement this, please. Do you mean `NSLocalizedDescriptionKey`? Also, you've added the record object. Should I keep the `publicDatabase.fetch` configured this way when subscribing the user? I'm getting errors when adding your line.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is definitely possible.

**== Step 1 ==**

Create a `Localizable.strings` file in your `/Resources` folder of your Xcode project and put this in it:

```
"%1$@" = "%1$@";
```

**== Step 2 ==**

Add more details to the `CKSubscriptions.NotificationInfo()` you have like this:

```
let info = CKSubscription.NotificationInfo()
  
//Notification Title
info.titleLocalizationKey = "%1$@"
info.titleLocalizationArgs = ["title"] //Matches a CKRecord field on your Episode recordType

//Notification Subtitle (Optional)
info.subtitleLocalizationKey = "%1$@"
info.subtitleLocalizationArgs = ["subtitle"] //Matches a CKRecord field

//Notification Body/Message
info.alertLocalizationKey = "%1$@"
info.alertLocalizationArgs = ["details"] //Matches a CKRecord field

//One key for each of the above to fetch
info.desiredKeys = ["title", "subtitle", "details"]

//Always set this to true
info.shouldSendContentAvailable = true

//More Notification Options
info.shouldBadge = false
info.soundName = "Notification.wav"

subscription.notificationInfo = info
```

If your `Episode` recordType doesn't have `title`, `subtitle`, and `details`, you might have to add extra fields on it that show the exact text you want to appear in a notification.

Comment: Though other suggestions may have worked with more info this worked out of the box though it's still somewhat of a mystery. My fields are "channelName" and "caption" for example. How does the notification know which is the title can body? Is it the order of the desiredKeys? How can I add an image from a URL?

Comment: Oh I see the keys are different, sorry that's my dyslexia. Still confused about the image.

Comment: I've never tried adding an image to a push notification, so I'm not familiar with that, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

One way of achieving this is to subscribe for record changes on `Episode`, for example when new episode is created for channel id

```
let subscription = CKQuerySubscription(
     recordType: "Episode",
     predicate: NSPredicate(format: "channelID == %@", ID),
     subscriptionID: CKQuerySubscription.ID("episode_subscription"),
     options: [
        CKQuerySubscription.Options.firesOnRecordCreation,
     ]
 )
```

than save the subscription to database

```
let info = CKSubscription.NotificationInfo()
info.shouldSendContentAvailable = true
subscription.notificationInfo = info
        
let operation = CKModifySubscriptionsOperation(
   subscriptionsToSave: [subscription],
   subscriptionIDsToDelete: nil
)
```

and last step is to handle the notification in your `AppDelegate` in `didReceiveRemoteNotification`

```
if let dict = userInfo as? [String: NSObject] {
   if let notification = CKNotification(fromRemoteNotificationDictionary: dict) {
     if let queryNotification = notification as? CKQueryNotification { 
       //Fetch record with id
       let operation = CKFetchRecordsOperation(recordIDs:[queryNotification.recordID])
       ...
       //Show notification when fetch is completed.
     }
  }     
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm willing to give this a go, but when you say "Show notification when the fetch is completed" do you mean to show it now as a local notification? I'm not sure how to change the notification content from the record returned in the operation and "show it". Googling is only explaining how to show local notifications that way.